# Multi-channel SATA RAID card to RAID 4 Bay Enclosure

Tags: raid, sata, hardware-raid, enclosures

I have a [Mediasonic ProBox HF2-SU3S2 4 Bay 3.5" Hard Drive Enclosure](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B003X26VV4?ref_=cm_cr-mr-title).

The box only has one eSATA port and one USB 3.0 port on the back. According to the manual of this storage box I need to get a SATA card that handles minimum 4 channels per port.

Looking for a good/affordable SATA card, I would like for the card to handle my 4 HDs in the enclosure and represent them as 1 HD (as seen by the OS) using some form of RAID or spanning.

I did buy a SATA controller cards which handles multi channel per port, but doesn't RAID or span the HDs. Windows recognizes the 4 HDs but doesn't allow RAID or Spanning. I tried doing through USB and doesn't do it either.

Speaking with some local hardware vendors, I was told that I cannot get a multi channel card that RAIDs through a single port.

Searching some hardware vendors online, it's hard to determine if the cards they sell supports RAID on a single port with multi-channel.

So my question is are they right? Multi-channel RAID cards don't exist.

Comment: What you are talking about has nothing to do with multi-channel. What you need is a card that supports *port multipliers*. Cards that do what you want (support "multi-channel/port multipliers" and RAID) do exist. IIRC most Silicon Image and Marvell based fake-RAID cards do both.